# My debug text shows garbage

Tags: c, game-engine, 2d-games

I'm making a simple game in C using the amazing [raylib](http://raylib.com) and I tried to print my player coordinates but the x value that should update stays at `0` and the y value that should stay the same prints a garbage value that changes according to my player's x value

My code is as follows:
([here](https://gist.github.com/omrisim210/5ca2c69780e647c59c9296f7e4424673) is a commented version, sorry if there's too much code embedded in the post)

```
// WIP

#include "raylib.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

//#define PLATFORM_WEB
#define DEBUG

#if defined(PLATFORM_WEB)
    #include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#endif

#define PLAYER_MAX_LIFE         5

typedef enum GameScreen { LOGO, TITLE, GAMEPLAY, ENDING } GameScreen;

typedef struct Player {
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 size;
    int life;
} Player;

typedef struct Food {
    Vector2 position;
    int value;
} Food;

static int  screenWidth = 800;
static int  screenHeight = 450;

static int  framesCounter;
static bool gameOver;
static bool pause;

#if defined(DEBUG)
static char* debugText;
#endif

static Player player;

static void InitGame(void);         // Initialize game
static void UpdateGame(void);       // Update game (one frame)
static void DrawGame(void);         // Draw game (one frame)
static void UnloadGame(void);       // Unload game
static void UpdateDrawFrame(void);  // Update and Draw (one frame)

int main()
{
    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "what should i name this piece of s##t game");

    InitGame();

#if defined(PLATFORM_WEB)
    emscripten_set_main_loop(UpdateDrawFrame, 0, 1);
#else

    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose())    // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
        UpdateGame();
        DrawGame();
    }
#endif

    UnloadGame();         // Unload loaded data (textures, sounds, models etc)

    CloseWindow();        // Close window and OpenGL context    
    return 0;
}

void InitGame(void)
{
    player.position = (Vector2){ screenWidth/2, screenHeight - screenHeight/8 };
    player.size = (Vector2){ screenWidth/10, 20 };
    player.life = PLAYER_MAX_LIFE;
    debugText = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
}

void UpdateGame(void)
{
    if (!gameOver)
    {
        if (IsKeyPressed('P')) pause = !pause;

        if (!pause)
        {
            if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT))                                  player.position.x -= 5;
            if ((player.position.x - player.size.x/2) <= 0)           player.position.x = player.size.x/2;
            if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT))                                 player.position.x += 5;
            if ((player.position.x + player.size.x/2) >= screenWidth) player.position.x = screenWidth - player.size.x/2;

        #if defined(DEBUG)
            debugText = FormatText("screen: %dx%d\nx: %d\ny: %d", screenWidth, screenHeight, player.position.x, player.position.y);
        #endif    
            if (player.life <= 0) gameOver = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_ENTER))
        {
            InitGame();
            gameOver = false;
        }
    }
}

void DrawGame(void)
{
    BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

        if (!gameOver)
        {
        #if defined(DEBUG)
            DrawText(debugText, 50, 70, 20, BLACK);
        #endif
            DrawRectangle(0, screenHeight - screenHeight/8 + (screenHeight - screenHeight/8)/36, screenWidth, screenHeight/9, GREEN);

            DrawRectangle(player.position.x - player.size.x/2, player.position.y - player.size.y/2, player.size.x, player.size.y, BLACK);

            for (int i = 0; i < player.life; i++) DrawRectangle(20 + 40*i, screenHeight - 30, 35, 10, LIGHTGRAY);

            if (pause) DrawText("GAME PAUSED", screenWidth / 2 - MeasureText("GAME PAUSED", 40)/2, screenHeight/2 - 40, 40, GRAY);
        }
        else DrawText("PRESS [ENTER] TO PLAY AGAIN", screenWidth/2 - MeasureText("PRESS [ENTER] TO PLAY AGAIN", 20)/2, screenHeight/2 - 50, 20, GRAY);

    EndDrawing();
}

void UnloadGame(void)
{
    free(debugText);
}

void UpdateDrawFrame(void)
{
    UpdateGame();
    DrawGame();
}    

static void UpdateFood(void)
{
    //TODO: Implement logic
}
```

I believe the problematic part to be this:

`debugText = FormatText("screen: %dx%d\nx: %d\ny: %d", screenWidth, screenHeight, player.position.x, player.position.y);`

Either accessing player.position.x and player.position.y doesn't work or maybe there's some sort of overflow? I really don't know so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If on Gnu/Linux, GDB is your friend.

Comment: I'm on windows, using the "default" workflow that consists of notepad++ scripts and MinGW to compile although I'm gonna try using gdb on the executable

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/raymath.h) a `Vector2` has 2 *float* members, but in your debug print you're using `%d`. While `FormatText` might handle that differently from the standard funcs, I'd check that too. If it ends up using the standard formatting funcs under the hood, then that's undefined behavior.

Comment: Your string is larger than 20 characaters. 
Try `debugText = malloc(sizeof(char) * 40);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had a feeling it was a stupid mistake.  

`debugText = FormatText("screen: %dx%d\nx: %f\ny: %f", screenWidth, screenHeight, player.position.x, player.position.y);` and `debugText = malloc(sizeof(char) * 40);` worked

Comment: Without knowing what `FormatText` does exactly this is speculation, but I'd guess your debug leaks memory. Since FormatText returns a pointer, it overwrites the pointer that was in `debugText`, so the previously allocated space is lost.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect. the use of the expression in the parameter to `malloc()` just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing that expression.

Comment: the posted code contains a memory leak.  the pointer, returned from 'malloc()' and placed into `debugText` is being overlayed by the call to `FormatText()`  Suggest initializing `debugText` to NULL rather than  via `malloc()`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that one of the problems was an overflow and the other one was using the wrong format specifiers
Changing these two lines fixed it:

```
-- debugText = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
++ debugText = malloc(sizeof(char) * 40);

-- debugText = FormatText("screen: %dx%d\nx: %d\ny: %d", screenWidth, screenHeight, player.position.x, player.position.y);
++ debugText = FormatText("screen: %dx%d\nx: %f\ny: %f", screenWidth, screenHeight, player.position.x, player.position.y);
```

Comment: I don't understand how the `malloc()` has anything to do with this.  I;m not familiar with raylib, but it looks like `FormatText()` returns a new pointer instead of doing anything with whatever buffer `debugText` is already pointing to (as far as I can tell, `FormatText()` doesn't know anything about that buffer).  It actually looks to me that the `malloc()`'ed block is actually leaked.

Comment: Also, from the few examples I can see on the web, there doesn't seem to be a way to 'free' the bufffer returned from `FormatText()` so I'm betting that it returns a static buffer that gets reused.  If that;'s the case then calling `FormatText()` in one place then using that buffer later in a `DrawText()` call might result in the formatted text being lost (replaced by subsequent formatted text).  All the examples I see of `FormatText()` being used are of the form: `DrawText(FormatText(...), ...)`.

Comment: You're right, I got confused and mixed up my old buggy implementation with the correct way of doing things. Thanks for making me aware of this

Comment: Michael Burr is right, [FormatText()](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/text.c#L461) just uses a static buffer that is reused every call, that function is intended to generate a static string just to be draw on the screen and be discarded after that.